# why use TCP use a basic timer which cannot be always exact whereas timer in java is always precise?

Tags: java, tcp

I am reading "TCP/IP illustrated", and the book illustrates that kernel implements a unit-timer like 500ms for TCP and all other TCP timers use this unit-timer. But the first period cannot be exact. For example, a retransmission timer is 12 units (6s), but the first time period may be in the middle so the actual time may be 5.5-6s.

On the contrary, when in java, it is easy to implement Thread.sleep(5000ms) which is precise and not a range.

So whey TCP timer cannot be exact whereas java can?

Comment: See the Javadoc. `Thread.sleep()` is not precise, and neither is any other timer in Java.

Comment: @user207421 javadoc says "Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds plus the specified number of nanoseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers" . And I try to answer for the mechanics of more accurate control of the timer.

Comment: Exactly. 'Subject to the accuracy of system timers and schedulers'. You were asking why Java timers are more precise than system timers, and the documentation clearly states that they aren't.

Comment: @user207421 I think the question is ok. it is true the java timer is more precise than tcp implementation of the timer unit, and I think the logic I have explained in the answer. if your only focus is the limit on the wording strictly not the mechanics, all are subject to CPU clock.

Comment: It is *not* true that the Java timers are more precise than the operating system's, and the Javadoc you quoted specifically says so. Read it again.

Comment: @user207421 I am not saying the operating system but TCP timer which is 500ms granularity for BSD implementation. You should read my answer first?

Answer (score -1):

I kind of understand it and wanna check my answer. Java and Tcp timer both use a unit timer to count for the time period. The unit is limited by CPU which can be thousands of MHz meaning the clock is ns level. So the unit timer has a good choice of the granularity of the time. As for web service which tends to be slow, TCP chooses hundreds of ms while for java a tinier unit is chosen.